# file_get_contents() returns extra underscore on angular.callbacks

Tags: php

I built a PHP file with the sole purpose of hiding the API keys for Google Search, but part of the file_get_contents() always echo `angular.callbacks._0_({` instead of `angular.callbacks._0({`

This small change makes the rest of the response worthless as Angular throws `Uncaught TypeError: angular.callbacks._0_ is not a function`. Although the workaround does works flawlessly, I would like to know if someone found the root of this issue or a better solution that is strictly PHP (no curl or any other package.)

**search.php**

```
<?php // Created by Deovandski on 2/14/2016
header('Content-type: application/json');

# Setup Base URL and array for Parameters
$host = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?';
$queries = array();
$queries['cx'] = "XXX";// CSE KEY
$queries['key'] = "XXX"; // API KEY

# Setup possible incoming params
if (isset($_GET['search_term'])) $queries['q'] = $_GET['search_term'];
if (isset($_GET['result_count'])) $queries['result_count'] = $_GET['result_count'];
if (isset($_GET['callback'])) $queries['callback'] = $_GET['callback'];

# Build query and Final URL
$queriesURL = http_build_query($queries) . "\n";
$finalURL = $host.$queriesURL;
echo $finalURL;
/* echo $finalURL output (I only edited the keys out):
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?cx=XXX&key=XXX&q=Hatsune+Miku&result_count=10&callback=angular.callbacks._0
*/
// Setup Response
$response = file_get_contents($finalURL);

// workaround
$fixedResponse = str_replace("angular.callbacks._0_", "angular.callbacks._0", $response);
echo $fixedResponse; 

?>
```

This is part of a correct Google API response:

```
// API callback
angular.callbacks._0({
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
 },
```

I put up a live version of this issue that can be seen on my [FTP server](http://cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~skibinsk/). The PHP file can be viewed through this [link](http://cs.ndsu.nodak.edu/~skibinsk/) (AngularJS parameters included on it).

Comment: Show result of `echo $finalURL` without api and css keys.

Comment: echo $finalURL output is now right under it.

Comment: Tested with the specified input parameters - everything is working properly, no extra underscore is added. So the problem somewhere else, not in `file_get_contents`

Comment: Did you comment out the workaround? If so, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Yes, I commented out. 5.5.31

Comment: Live version of this issue added... I was able to replicate it on 5.5.12 on my WAMP Stack and also on PHP version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30 on an Apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the escape sequences `\n`. Which is passed as part of the request. And which is interpreted as space and as part of the callback function name and replaced by the side of the API to underline.

To understand just try this option and look at the result:

```
$queriesURL = http_build_query($queries) . "\n" . "after";
```

So just take away a newline.